# Counting instances in a pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
TF  name  
0   A
1   A
0   A
0   A
1   B
1   B
0   B
1   B
1   B
```

I need to produce a resulting dataframe that would count how many 0's and 1's each person in my dataframe has.

So the result for the above would be:

```
name  True  False
A     3     1
B     1     4
```

I don't think `groupby` would work in this instance. Any solution other than looping and counting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can perform `groupby` letting *TF* be the grouped key. Take the corresponding [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) of the *name* column to get distinct counts.

Unstack `level=0` of the multi-index series so that a dataframe object gets produced. Finally, rename the integer columns by type-casting them as boolean values.

```
df.groupby('TF')['name'].value_counts().unstack(0).rename(columns=bool)
```

[image]

To have the column names take on string values:

1) Use `lambda` function:

```
<...operations on df...>.rename(columns=lambda x: str(x.astype(bool)))
```

2) Or chain the syntaxes together:

```
<...operations on df...>.rename(columns=bool).rename(columns=str)
```

Comment: It works. But how do I make False and True Column names though. Now where I do `df['False']` it gives me KeyError

Comment: Seems you want them as strings instead. Just replacing `bool` with `lambda x: str(x.astype(bool))` could be one possiblility.

Answer (score 2):

I would first convert your columns to boolean and then group by both name and TF and then unstack the boolean column TF.

```
df['TF']=df['TF'].astype(bool)
df.groupby(['name', 'TF']).size().unstack('TF')

TF    False  True 
name              
A         3      1
B         1      4
```